# Jmeter - How to execute two scripts together

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

I have two scenarios which need to be executed together:

```
Scenario 1: Launch ---> Login..........---> Logout. Basically it creates something. There is a unique id received.

Scenario 2: Launch ---> Login..........---> Logout. This updates the unique id received from the previous scenario.
```

Scenario 1 needs to be run with 70 users and 2 with another 70 users. Totally 140 users for one hour.

Scenario 2 has a dependency on 1. The unique id generated from 1 needs to be passed into 2.

How do I proceed with this execution? Thanks in Advance.

Regards,
Ajith

Answer (score 0):

Normally you should be using different [Thread Groups](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) for simulating different groups of business users so you need to configure the Thread Groups like:

[image]

In order to run both Thread Groups at the same time make sure that `Run Thread Groups consecutively` is **not checked** at [Test Plan](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Test_Plan) level

For passing the unique ID from the 1st Thread Group to 2nd Thread Group there are 2 approaches:

1. Use [__setProperty() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__setProperty) (maybe in combination with [__threadNum() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__threadNum) if each user need to have its own ID) to store the unique ID into a JMeter Property in the 1st Thread Group. The property can be read via [__P() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__P) in the 2nd Thread Group
2. Use [Inter-Thread Communication Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-use-the-inter-thread-communication-plugin-in-jmeter)